# What is the best way to handle comp time?

Tags: hours

Different managers in our company handle comp time differently, which creates some issues. Some track it and then allow employees to schedule it as in advance. Others give it out whenever it is asked for, but the problem is this: we usually accrue comp time in a crisis. A system goes down and we work late. There are still issues the next day, and some of us with managers that require scheduling in advance are left to pick up the pieces, while those who can simply ask and get it are at home sleeping.

Is there a better way to handle this on a company-wide level? What are the recommended ways to handle comp time?

Comp time definition:
From en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overtime : Time off in lieu; compensatory time; or comp time refers to a type of work schedule arrangement that allows (or requires) workers to take time off instead of, or in addition to, receiving overtime pay. A worker may receive overtime pay plus equal time off for each hour worked on certain agreed days, such as bank holidays.

Comment: Hi Melissa. I'd like to help, but would you be willing to more narrowly define the problem you'd like answered? Are you trying to get a consistency in the way comp time is issued? Are you trying to get more consistency in the way it's allowed to be scheduled? Do you want more people to be like you (schedule ahead of time), because you only feel it's fair that all employees have the same restrictions that your position has? Are you seeking a more flexible schedule for your own position? Are you highlighting something you feel is unfair, and if so what specifically is unfair about it?

Comment: Do you want suggestions on how you should get your company to change, or suggestions about what it should change to? You seem to be asking the latter, but implying the former.

Comment: I have edited to clarify that what I am looking for is a "best practices" for comp time.

Comment: Melissa, as explained in our [help], best practices and other discussion-like topics are not a good fit for our format. As it currently is phrased, you aren't defining what problem you have, and how you want to solve it, which is why it's been put on hold. Please re-read @jeff's comment again, and try to clarify your question with another [edit]. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In general, inconsistent rules are worse than consistent rules. You are in an unfair environment. This is not something you can fix. It's HR's or high level management's job to make sure the comp time policy is company wide consistent.

Talk to your direct report manager first. If he is unable to help it (he can only do what he can do), then go to the HR and explain to them what you observe. Ask them to help to define  company wide comp time rules for every employee to follow.

Your company has multiple managers. I presume there is an HR department. If for some reasons there is no HR department for you to go to, you are having much bigger problems - your company is not well organized. In that case, I suggest you to go to the next level manager.

I think cancelling comp time altogether is very unlikely after you go to HR. Your company already has it. Cancelling it would cause trouble for all the employees. The worst thing it could happen is the problem you are having would remian unsolved. Of course, you may be put on some list after you go to HR. It's up to you. You want to work in an unfair environment or you want to help the company to fix this problem.

Comment: Be very wary of going to HR with this. Most companies prefer not to give official comp time because it creates a finanical obligation on their part. Most likely result of going to HR is that no one gets comp time.

Comment: @HLGEM [Office of Personell Management](http://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/pay-administration/fact-sheets/compensatory-time-off/) has official comp time policies for US government employees. Comp time is part of employee compansation package. Not to give comp time is like vacation reduction. I don't know about you, I myself don't want to work for companies who would reduce my benifits.

Comment: Comp time is illegal in many instances (it cannot be offered instead of overtime if the employee is eligible for overtime) and it is never required for salaried employees. But if they do it officially, they have to give you time and half just like overtime and they have to pay you when you leave if you have unused official comp time. This makes it  in the company's best interest not to offer it offically. I have never worked anywhere that comp time wasn't unoffically offered though.

Comment: @Melissa I updated my answer. Depending on your location/local labor law, comp time is a sometimes silent agreement. OPM (see my comment above) has official policies for it. The bottom line is that you need help from HR/high level management to fix it.